# How get original message after get an errorHandler and write a file

Tags: email, spring-integration, dsl

I've been building a Spring integration Service Email using Java **DSL**. 
This service must have a recovery policy in order to retry sending the emails but I'm not getting success.
A brief story: The application recieve a Payload and Header and try to send to email server. It tries 3 times and in case of failure, it creates a new file with Header and Body of message.

**How could I get the original Message(Header and Payload) and put the information pair in a json file, in case of failure to send the email?**

Thanks.

This is my beans and the service:

```
/**
 * ################# 
 * MESSAGE ENDPOINTS
 * #################
 */

@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller() {
    return Pollers              
            .fixedRate(NumberUtils.createLong(QUEUE_RATE))
            .maxMessagesPerPoll(NumberUtils.createLong(QUEUE_CAPACITY))
            .errorHandler(e -> LOG.error("Exception : " + e.getMessage()))
            .get();
}


@Bean
public MessageChannel recoveryChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}


@MessagingGateway 
public static interface MailService {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "mail.input")
    void sendMail(String body, @Headers Map<String,String> headers);        
}

@Bean
public RetryPolicy retryPolicy() {
    final Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> map = 
            new HashMap<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean>() {
                {
                    put(MailSendException.class,true);
                    put(RuntimeException.class, true);
                }
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
            };
    final RetryPolicy ret = new SimpleRetryPolicy(3, map, true);
    return ret;
}

@Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
    final RetryTemplate ret = new RetryTemplate();
    ret.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy());
    ret.setThrowLastExceptionOnExhausted(false);
    return ret;
}

@Bean
public Advice retryAdvice() {
    final RequestHandlerRetryAdvice advice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();       
    advice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
    RecoveryCallback<Object> recoveryCallBack = new ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer(recoveryChannel());

    advice.setRecoveryCallback(recoveryCallBack);
    return advice;
}


private MailSendingMessageHandlerSpec mailOutboundAdapter(){
    MailSendingMessageHandlerSpec msmhs = 
            Mail.outboundAdapter(emailServerHost())
            .port(serverPort())
            .credentials(MAIL_USER_NAME, MAIL_PASSWORD)
            .protocol(emailProtocol())
            .javaMailProperties(p -> p
                    .put("mail.debug", "true")
                    .put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable",enableSSL())
                    .put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", 5000)
                    .put("mail.smtp.timeout", 5000));
    return msmhs;
}

@Bean
public FileWritingMessageHandler fileOutboundAdapter(){
    FileWritingMessageHandler fwmhs = Files
            .outboundAdapter(new File("logs/errors/"))
            .autoCreateDirectory(true)
            .get();     

    return fwmhs;
}


/**
 * ################ 
 * FLOWS
 * ################
 */


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow smtp(){  

    return IntegrationFlows.from("mail.input")
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue())
            .handle(this.mailOutboundAdapter(), 
                    e -> e.id("smtpOut")
                            .advice(retryAdvice())
                    )
            .get();
}

@Bean 
public IntegrationFlow errorFlow(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from(recoveryChannel())
                            .transform(Transformers.toJson())
                            .enrichHeaders(c -> c.header(FileHeaders.FILENAME, "emailErrors"))
                            .handle(this.fileOutboundAdapter())
                            .get();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message has a payload `MessagingException`. It has two properties `cause` and `failedMessage`.

The failed message is the message at the point of failure, with headers and payload.

Comment: My payload in the errorFlow() method only have the MessageException:

Comment: Right, so you need to add a trasformer `.transform("payload.failedMessage")` before `.transform(Transformers.toJson())`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works!

Comment: Now, I stick to the transformation of a Message to a Json like this structure:  { "Headers": { ["abc" : "123" ]}, "Payload": { " def" : "aaaaaaaaa"} }